# Changelog difference between version 2.3 and 3.0

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I tried the application framework for a while using version 2.3
Now I'm planning the development of 2 web applications (MPA with ASP.NET MVC 5.x
)

What's the differences between version 2.3 and 3.0 version?

I didn't found any changelog files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Changelog

The release notes for the framework (ABP) can be found here: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/releases

The release notes for the template (MPA with ASP.NET MVC 5.x) can be found here: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/releases

## Notable differences

Most importantly, ABP v3.0.0 is based on .NET Standard 2.0.

- This concerns you regardless if you are on MVC 5.x, .NET Framework 4.x or .NET Core 2.x.
- You should use VS2017 15.3.3+.

  - For VS2015, you may try installing [NuGet client 3.6 or higher](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/24) but that [may no longer work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355233/asp-net-boilerplate-error-building-new-project-for-mvc-and-ef-combo/46355567#comment79701773_46355567).