# The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

This is the first time I have used abp to build a project using templates.
I tried a lot of ways to find out how to fix this problem but failed.

- Abp package version: 3.0.0
- Base framework: .Net Framework 4.6.1

> Exception: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced.You must add a reference to assembly '**netstandard,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51**'.

Comment: install latest Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ABP v3.0.0 is based on .NET Standard 2.0.

- This concerns you regardless if you are on MVC 5.x, .NET Framework 4.x or .NET Core 2.x.
- You should use VS2017 15.3.3+.

  - For VS2015, you may try installing [NuGet client 3.6 or higher](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/24) but that [may no longer work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355233/asp-net-boilerplate-error-building-new-project-for-mvc-and-ef-combo/46355567#comment79701773_46355567).