# Net standard Library missing reference in ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate, .net-standard-2.0, asp.net-boilerplate

every time i clone Abp.ModuleZero to my machine when i run nuget command update-database the error show me and when i build the solution in viusal studio the project doesn't build and show many errors in error list console window
most of them is like :

> The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
>   You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

i try to install Netstandard.library package from package manager console window but doesn't  any sense.

my visual studio IDE version is 2015 Update 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ABP v3.0.0 is based on .NET Standard 2.0.

- This concerns you regardless if you are on MVC 5.x, .NET Framework 4.x or .NET Core 2.x.
- You should use VS2017 15.3.3+.

  - For VS2015, you may try installing [NuGet client 3.6 or higher](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/24) but that [may no longer work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355233/asp-net-boilerplate-error-building-new-project-for-mvc-and-ef-combo/46355567#comment79701773_46355567).

> i think downgrade to earlier version of this framework is good solution for me, where can i download early version of ABP framework like 2.3.4?

I don't see why you would download the *framework*, but it's on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/releases).

If you meant download a *template* that uses an earlier version of ABP:

- You can only choose the project version for [premium startup templates](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates#PaidStartupTemplatesArea).
- You can build your own from [module-zero-core-template/releases/tag/v2.5.1](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/releases/tag/v2.5.1).

  - You need to rename the files and folders yourself.

Comment: thank you @aaron .this approaches is good for me. and i download source earlier version from github.